# Get ANY value in a Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can I get a value (no value in particular, just any value) in a C# Dictionary without any key? I mean something that just returns ANY value contained in the collection.

I know of the existence of Linq First(), but I don't know exactly how expensive that is, and I am developing a game, so performance is a concern for me. That said, the operation is not done every frame, so it's kind of fine, but is there a more efficient method aside from First()?

Comment: Expensive as in how? Have you tested anything? Just any item from dictionary? If you just want any item then why store in dictionary? Also if you know about `.First` and don't know how "expensive" you can test it first..

Comment: You can use the .SelectMany

Comment: @GiladGreen I don't know if you read my question, it clearly states "I don't know how expansive that is" it's literally the second line.

Comment: @JoshAdams doesn't that cause memalloc?

Comment: @Alakanu - I read it. My point is that you do not define what expensive is? You mean time to retrieve item - test it?...

Comment: @Alakanu yes, it would allocate to memory, i thought you were just trying to avoid calling .first over and over. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Why would you consider any method to be faster than `First`? It´s the fastest of all, since it breaks as soon as one item was found.

Comment: @GiladGreen time to retrieve item, heap allocation are both sensible parameters

Comment: @HimBromBeere I don't know, therefore I asked. Does it cause any heap allocation or something?

Comment: Don´t overcomplicate things only because you think a certain line of code *may* cost a nanosecond more then another one. **Allways** measure, if you are in doubt of performance.

Comment: If you don't care *which* item is returned, perhaps you could use `Stack<T>` instead of `Dictionary<T>`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's only one specific case, regularly I access it with keys.

Comment: In the cases where you don't access it with keys, what criteria do you use to find the value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`First()` will use LINQ, which builds on `IEnumerable<T>`. Now; `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` has a custom value-type enumerator, so using LINQ will cause *boxing* of the enumerator (LINQ isn't very good at using custom enumerators). A slightly more frugal approach may be to simply do something like:

```
foreach(var pair in dictionary) return pair.Value;
return default; // if empty
```

Which is broadly equivalent to:

```
using (var iter = a.GetEnumerator()) {
    return iter.MoveNext() ? iter.Current.Value : default;
}
```

Note that this won't be random in any way - nor will it predictably sorted. Probably not great properties for a game.

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` also has a member `Values` of type `IEnumerable<TValue>` and `Keys` of type `IEnumerable<TKey>`.  This means you can do `dict.Values.First()` to get a value out.  This may not be the most performant option though.

Answer (score 0):

Access by key is always faster than linq operations:

```
var contents = myDictionary[key];
```

Comment: My bad, I thought it was clear in that ANY that I didn't want to use no keys but just get one value contained in the dictionary. I've corrected my question, thanks.

Comment: @Alankanu - How will you get this value?  What criteria will you use to select it?  Do you always want the first one?

Comment: No, just any. I don't care if it's the first one, the last one, and I don't even care if it's always the same or if it's always random. I just want to get ANY value from the collection without passing in a key.